# Get-RDUsersession does not work from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

So this has me perplexed. We have a Powershell script that calls the following command:

```
$id = get-rdusersession
```

When we run the script from the Powershell console everything works just fine. However, when we run this very same script from the Windows Task Scheduler things fail. In the transcript is the following:

```
get-rdusersession : A Remote Desktop Services deployment does not exist on OurServer.OurDomain.com.
```

This deployment definitely exists- and the entire scripts runs fine from the Powershell console. I have tried all manner of

```
-CollectionBroker
```

to no avail. The scheduled task is set to run as administrator with elevated permissions. also the command parameters

```
 -noprofile -executionpolicy unrestricted -noninteractive
```

are all set.
Anyone have any idea at all what the problem is?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest there is no code INSIDE of this that is failing - the script cannot get the rdusersession in order to continue with the rest of the script. The question is not too broad, it is EXACTLY what the issue is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a brain fart and neither recognized the cmdlet and also interpreted it as you wrote the failing cmdlet. My mistake.

Comment: This question isn't off topic here, but you might want to ask something similar at https://serverfault.com about this behavior. That community may understand Remote Desktop deployments better than this one due to it being focused on enterprise services and infrastructure.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I may do that too- figured since it was Powershell someone here may know. This is very odd behavior; I have read a few posts about 'double hop' credentials in powershell but I don't really know if it applies here or not.

Comment: I don't have any confidence to post this as an answer but my first thought is that there could be some issue with running this as SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE (if you are not running as a proper service account). I'm not sure of the scope of these cmdlets and whether they list only sessions for the current user or all sessions for all users.

Comment: I can't see how it's a double hop issue considering you haven't mentioned executing this in a remote context. Your wording sounds like you can run it interactively, but it fails when you run the script from task scheduler on the same server.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest yeah this is really weird. I moved the entire thing to a function that is called in the same script and now it works fine with the same credentials. Move it back to the original code and no go. Strange.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Remote Desktop Services proper (just general RDP connections) but is it possible you're running with one of the built-in machine accounts (e.g. `SYSTEM`, `NETWORK SERVICE`), and the machine account does not have permission to access RDS? This would explain why interactive it works, if your user has access, but does not work when run as one of the `built-in` principals.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest we tried every manner of accounts and security we could think of. Nothing worked. It is so strange. And yet moving the exact same code into a function worked.

Comment: Without seeing your original script I don't think SO can identify why your code wasn't working outside of a function body.